# G-Suit mail pricing , What is per user mean?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, google-workspace, mail-server

I want to buy a g-suit mail. 
I already have a domain. I want to buy an email server from the g-suit. 
When I visited g-suit pricing, there was "Per User" billing details. Actually I don't know what it means.

what is per user means? is that directs to per domain?
If I want to create 20 mail id in the same domain will it count as one user or 20 users?

as I already told, 20 mail id will be on the same domain name

like user1@mydomain.com, user2@mydomain.com ..... user20@mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per-User means, if you want to make alias mail it won't consider as a user. You won't get any separate Gmail for this mail. Alias mail won't get any extra storage.
Say your domain name is abc.com and you want to create three mail and want to pay for a single user then you will create salesteam@abc.com and two other mail will be sale1@abc.com and sale1@abc.com. Then you can send mail from salesteam@abc.com for all other mail.

Gmail's official statement is:
https://workspace.google.com/faq/

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to pay 20 users.

Here I add a [link](https://gsuite.google.com/landing/partners/referral/trial.html?utm_source=sign-up&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=apps-referral-program&utm_content=SU2RQ36) with a small discount